# MongoDB: return 0 for $count of certain values (aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
   $match : { platform_id : ... }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$type",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}]);
```

The possible values for `$type` are `0` or `1`.

Right now, I get a count of `0`s and `1`s if there are records with either type value (0 or 1).

But, if all the records have the same type (e.g. 1), how do I also get the count of `0`s to be 0?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938784/mongodb-aggregate-return-count-of-0-if-no-results) post, it looks like it might not be possible. Is that true in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **aggregate** can not fulfill your target. Need some JS code after it.

```
var aggr = db.collection.aggregate([{ 
       $match : { platform_id : ... }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {$ifNull : ["$type", 0]}, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }]);

var result = aggr.toArray(); // mongo shell V2.6+
// var result = aggr.result; // mongo shell before V2.6

[{_id : 0, count : 0}, {_id : 1, count : 0}].forEach(function(e) {
    var i = 0;
    var len = result.length;
    while (i < len && e._id != result[i]._id) ++i;
    if (i >= len) result.push(e);
});
// result is the final.
```

Comment: This is close. Let's say all the documents have `type` set to `1` (but `0` is an acceptable value. How do I get it to return `[{'count': 250, '_id': 1},{'count': 0, '_id': 0}]`?

Comment: @okoboko, It seems that you've modified your requirements. I've updated the answer accordingly.